# How to deny access to a folder in vb 10

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I want to code a program in which a folder wouldn't be accessible to any of the users. I set it's attribute-number to 7 hence it became hidden, system file and read-only. But the folder can be accessed by any users.

I want a code in which a Message-box appears saying that the access is denied while its opened. Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No program can do this. You need to set the security of the folder so the Administrator is the only one that can access it. [Folder Security](https://www.google.com/#q=setting+folder+security+windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `ICACLS`, run it in your code by using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`

```
' Your path here
Dim path As String = "X:\Path\Follows\Here.x"
Dim cmd As String = "icacls " & path & " /deny *S-1-1-0:(OI)(CI)(W,D,X)"
' You can also just use Process.Start even without "Imports System.Diagnostics"
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmd)
```